# How to prevent trials execution on the head

Tags: ray

I'm using ray.tune on an aws "Autoscaling GPU cluster". Currently, my head and workers all have a GPU and are all used to execute trials. I'm trying to move to a setup where the head doesn't have a GPU --
along the lines of how Ray's doc defines "Autoscaling GPU cluster". However, I keep running into CUDA problems on the head which makes sense since it is used for trials execution. The solution appears simple enough: I guess I need to prevent trials execution on the head but I can't find how. I tried various `resources_per_trial` values, same with `ray.init()` but didn't get this to work.

### Additional details:

- I use ray 0.8.6.
- I set `resources_per_trial={'gpu': 1}`
- I set `torch.device("cuda:0")` everywhere
- I use 1 head (cpu only) and 1 worker (gpu only), I required a minimum of 1 worker.

So everything is made to run only on GPU which is why I focused on preventing execution on the head.

Regarding errors and warnings, I get the following:

```
WARNING tune.py:318 -- Tune detects GPUs, but no trials are using GPUs. To enable trials to use GPUs, set tune.run(resources_per_trial={'gpu': 1}...) which allows Tune to expose 1 GPU to each trial. You can also override `Trainable.default_resource_request` if using the Trainable API.
```

```
WARNING ray_trial_executor.py:549 -- Allowing trial to start even though the cluster does not have enough free resources. Trial actors may appear to hang until enough resources are added to the cluster (e.g., via autoscaling). You can disable this behavior by specifying `queue_trials=False` in ray.tune.run().


WARNING worker.py:1047 -- The actor or task with ID ffffffffffffffff128bce290200 is pending and cannot currently be scheduled. It requires {CPU: 1.000000}, {GPU: 1.000000} for execution and {CPU: 1.000000}, {GPU: 1.000000} for placement, but this node only has remaining {node:10.160.26.189: 1.000000}, {object_store_memory: 12.304688 GiB}, {CPU: 3.000000}, {memory: 41.650391 GiB}. In total there are 0 pending tasks and 1 pending actors on this node. This is likely due to all cluster resources being claimed by actors. To resolve the issue, consider creating fewer actors or increase the resources available to this Ray cluster. You can ignore this message if this Ray cluster is expected to auto-scale.
```

Even when I wait for the gpu worker to be running I still get the above.

Finally, the error is:

```
ERROR trial_runner.py:520 -- Trial TrainableAE_a441f_00000: Error processing event.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/trial_runner.py", line 468, in _process_trial
    result = self.trial_executor.fetch_result(trial)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/tune/ray_trial_executor.py", line 430, in fetch_result
    result = ray.get(trial_future[0], DEFAULT_GET_TIMEOUT)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1467, in get
    values = worker.get_objects(object_ids, timeout=timeout)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 306, in get_objects
    return self.deserialize_objects(data_metadata_pairs, object_ids)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 281, in deserialize_objects
    return context.deserialize_objects(data_metadata_pairs, object_ids)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 312, in deserialize_objects
    self._deserialize_object(data, metadata, object_id))
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 252, in _deserialize_object
    return self._deserialize_msgpack_data(data, metadata)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 233, in _deserialize_msgpack_data
    python_objects = self._deserialize_pickle5_data(pickle5_data)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ray/serialization.py", line 221, in _deserialize_pickle5_data
    obj = pickle.loads(in_band)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/storage.py", line 136, in _load_from_bytes
    return torch.load(io.BytesIO(b))
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 593, in load
    return _legacy_load(opened_file, map_location, pickle_module, **pickle_load_args)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 773, in _legacy_load
    result = unpickler.load()
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 729, in persistent_load
    deserialized_objects[root_key] = restore_location(obj, location)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 178, in default_restore_location
    result = fn(storage, location)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 154, in _cuda_deserialize
    device = validate_cuda_device(location)
  File "/opt/anaconda/2020/envs/py_37_pands0.25/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/serialization.py", line 138, in validate_cuda_device
    raise RuntimeError('Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA '
RuntimeError: Attempting to deserialize object on a CUDA device but torch.cuda.is_available() is False. If you are running on a CPU-only machine, please use torch.load with map_location=torch.device('cpu') to map your storages to the CPU.
```

Comment: What's the cuda issue that you're running into?

Comment: Thanks, I added more details to my question. I also tried another setup where I test if `torch.cuda.is_available()` and modify the device to `cpu`. That crashed as well but that seemed like a hacky solution anyway so I didn't post it.

Comment: Can you try using `torch.device("cuda")` instead?

Comment: Thanks, just tried: `torch.device("cuda")` and `torch.device("cuda:0")` return the same error.

Comment: Can you also check if `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns True?

Comment: No, it's `False`. But I'm confused by that question. It crashes on the head which has no GPU so isn't it expected that `cuda.is_available()` returns `False`? I see that you're a contributor to the project, do you know a working example where the head doesn't have a GPU? It may be easier for me to compare that against what I did to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So usually, this is a problem due to the cuda drivers on the GPU worker nodes not matching the pytorch expected CUDA drivers. Sorry for the confusing question; I meant to say to check if `torch.cuda.is_available()` returns True on the GPU worker nodes.

Comment: thanks. This is not the problem here, everything works fine when the head has a GPU. So it seems from your comments that ray is supposed "to know" automatically when to use the head to execute trials or not? I set `resources_per_trial={'gpu': 1}` and you would expect ray not to execute trials on the head since it has no GPU?

Comment: Yep, I also do not expect Ray to execute trials on the head since it has no GPUs. Can you help file an issue and post a full example script here: http://github.com/ray-project/ray/issues/? Ping me when you've done so @richardliaw on github - more than happy to take a closer look!

Comment: thanks, this comment really put me on the right track.

Comment: awesome! Do you mind leaving a comment/issue on github suggesting how we can improve this? I suspect many other users also have the same problem, and it'd be great if the team could better understand this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to richliaw for comments. The solution became obvious once I stopped trying to prevent trials execution on the head and instead focused on finding why these were happening in the first place. The AMI on the head of my cluster had NVidia drivers and cuda installed on it. After I removed those ray stopped trying to execute on the head. So I guess this is how ray decides to send computation on the head when `resources_per_trial={'gpu': 1}`.

Comment: Doesn't work in my case - my head doesn't have a GPU (or any matching drivers, for that matter), but ray tune still tries to run tuning on this machine..

Comment: Which version of ray are you using?

Comment: latest at the moment (1.2.0). In any case, I'm trying a better approach - Ray Client: https://docs.ray.io/en/master/ray-client.html